# how to prove $2\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{11}$ is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to let $$2\sqrt{5} + \sqrt{11} = \frac{a}{b}$$ and find contradictions

(I set $b \ne 0$, $a$ and $b$ are in their simplest form) but I cannot find any

Comment: Let's say it is rational, then $a^2/b^2 - n$ is rational for all rational $n$. But I reckon that I can find an $n$, for which we can easily prove this false

Comment: Show $x^2-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ and then show $x^2-11$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q[\sqrt{5}]$.  That will do it.

Comment: If $r=2\sqrt5+\sqrt{11}$ is rational, then so is $\frac{r^2-141}4=\sqrt{55}.$ Can you prove that $\sqrt{55}$ is irrational?

Comment: @zipirovich Nevertheless my approach differs from these of presented there.

Comment: @szw1710 This is a duplicate, which means it should be closed as a duplicate, especially since the original question was the better of the two questions.  You can make a case if you choose, to ask for a merging of the answers to the original, but you cannot deny you answered a question that was asked and answered two days ago.

Comment: @amWhy Thanks for your remarks. Maybe the moderators could join all into one piece (too many answers there to write my own in the original question. My best regards.

Answer (score 4):

If $2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11}$ is rational, then also $$2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{11}=\frac{9}{2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11}}$$ would be rational. Subtracting two rationals $(2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11})-(2\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{11})=2\sqrt{11}$ we arrive at $2\sqrt{11}$ which must also be rational, hence $\sqrt{11}$ is rational, which is false (proof like $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational).

Answer (score 2):

Let $x= 2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11}.$  Then

$$x^2 = 4\sqrt{55} + 31.$$

So $4\sqrt{55} = x^2 -31$, and squaring again gives

$$x^4-62x^2 +81 = 0.$$

By the rational root theorem, the only possible rational roots are $\pm 3^k$, where $k=0,1,2,3,4.$   Since $x$ is a root, it must be one of these, but $x$ is between $7$ and $8$, so it can't equal a power of $3$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11}=r$ where $r$ is a rational number. Then

\begin{align}
   r - \sqrt{11} &= 2\sqrt 5\\
   r^2 - 2r\sqrt{11}+11 &= 20 \\
   r^2 - 9 &= 2r \sqrt{11} \\
   r - \dfrac{9}{r} &= 2\sqrt{11}
\end{align}

But this is a contradiction since $r - \dfrac{9}{r}$ is, by hypothesis, a rational number and $2\sqrt{11}$ is an irrational number.

Hence $r = 2\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{11}$ is an irrational number.